# Vlookup using wildcards in indexed column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I know how to use a wildcard with Vlookup on the reference value, but what about on the matched column index?

I know you can do for instance `VLOOKUP("*Hello*",A4:G4,2,FALSE)`

However, what if you wanted to match a cell that is "Hello", with another one that is "Why, Hello there!" (so the opposite i suppose)

My data is set in a way where a macro is going to ask if `A4` in `workbook 1` matches `C2:C25000` in `workbook 2` to return the corresponding value in D back to `workbook 1`. The thought is that when A4 in `workbook 1` says Its DHS Here, that I could input a value such as *DHS* in column C in workbook 2 and have it say its a match.

Is this possible?

Comment: The vlookup code was supposed to have asterisks before and after 'Hello' - sorry for that - should have wrote it in code.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to bild the lookup value by concatenating `*`'s, like this

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A4&"*",'[workbook 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$2:$D$25000,2,0)
```

(adjust sheet name to suit)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already planning on using a macro, what is the possibility of using an add-on? From my understanding, you are looking for *fuzzy lookup*. Excel created an add-on to accomplish this task found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011).

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem many time.  You need put the wildcard phrase in a different cell.

Cell B1 has this in the cell:  `*Hello*`

Your new formula:  VLOOKUP(B1,A4:G4,2,FALSE)

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the `"lookup value"` could be "Why, Hello There!" or "DHS Here" and you want that to match respectively with "Hello" and "DHS" in the lookup range.

Given that then for a formula approach try the following:

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(C2:C25000,A4)/(C2:C25000<>""),D2:D25000)`

Where A4 is the lookup value, insert workbook/worksheet references as required.

That will find the **last** "match" in C2:C25000, for **first** match you can use

`=INDEX(D2:D25000,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C25000,A4))*(C2:C25000<>""),0),0))`

Note: either of those could match partial "words" so if A4 is "Rat catcher" that might match with "cat" or "catch" as well as "rat" - you can add in spaces to force the match to be with whole words only, e.g. first formula can be addapted to:

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&C2:C25000&" "," "&A4&" ")/(C2:C25000<>""),D2:D25000)`

although that assumes all words separated by spaces with no punctuation.....

Comment: From @[Jonathon](http://superuser.com/users/268746/jonathan): Barry, that is just what I need to lookup room names in a list of abrreviations and return the room type as listed in ventilation codes. I normally think I'm pretty good with excel, but for this example, I'm stumped. Can you explain how it works? Thanks